# How to enable php extensions Array when installing Drupal on Windows 10

Tags: php, drupal

I've installed drupal-8.7.2 & php 7.3.6 (Thread Safe).

In php.ini, I uncommented this line:

`extension=pdo_sqlite`

When I run this from the command prompt

`php core/scripts/drupal quick-start demo_umami`

I get this error:

```
3/18 [====>-----------------------]
Verify requirements

In install.core.inc line 2287:

  PHP extensions: Disabled

  Array
```

I've also tried php 7.3.6 (Non Thread Safe) and 7.2.19 (Non Thread Safe & Thread Safe) [image]

I've also tried the command

`php core/scripts/drupal quick-start`

And then when prompted, I enter `demo_umami`, and then I get the above error again.

Comment: According to me, The comment you mentioned for below answer (i.e. uncomment extension=gd2) is the correct answer. Please add it as answer. It will help the people to quickly resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error actually means you are missing a PHP extension, but it is badly formatted when rendered to CLI (see this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2833864)), hence the `Array()` displayed instead of the extension name.

The missing library is probably 'gd', you can check [PHP requirements](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/system-requirements/php-requirements) (*core/modules/system/system.install*) for your drupal installation by running [DrupalConsole](https://github.com/hechoendrupal/DrupalConsole) command `drupal check`, or manually with `php -m`.

The following must be installed :

```
$required_extensions = [
    'date',
    'dom',
    'filter',
    'gd',
    'hash',
    'json',
    'pcre',
    'pdo',
    'session',
    'SimpleXML',
    'SPL',
    'tokenizer',
    'xml',
];
```

It has not always been the case but *core/composer.json* actually reflects the state of these PHP extensions, so running `composer create-project` might help to manage this.

Comment: Yep, I was just about to update this question with the following: I tried uncommenting several extensions at once and found that it got past the error*, so thru process of elimination, I found that this was the one that did it: `extension=gd2`

Thanks!
(*: And on to another error, but that's another story)